# Sequence based on the condition using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I need to create a sequence based on the data in a column, the sample table is as follows:

```
id | group 
101| bfd   
102| bfd
123| klm
563| kln
693| klm
```

The sequence to be provided is like, if group = bfd then new_id = id + sequence in <0-200>
if group = klm or kln then new_id = id + sequence in <201-499>

The output should be something like:

```
id | group | new_id
101| bfd   | 1010 
102| bfd   | 1021
123| klm   | 123201
563| kln   |563202
693| klm   | 693203
```

I tried the following code

```
select * from(
SELECT id, group,
CASE
    WHEN group in 'bfd' THEN concat(ID, -1 +ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group order by ID))  
    WHEN group='klm' or group="kln" THEN concat(ID, 200 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group order by id))
    END  as new_id
FROM table2)
order by id;
```

How do I provide the limiting condition for row numbers to stop at 200 for particular group?

Comment: What will you do if there are 201 bfd? Repeatedly use 200? Put nothing for all subsequent ones?

Comment: Why do you think you even need this new ID column?  Note that even if you get an answer here, should your table data change, or should new data be added, you might have to recompute the new ID column again.

Comment: by the way, in your expected output, you are treating `klm` and `kln` as same group with same running sequence. But your query does not handle that `OVER(PARTITION BY group order by id)`

Comment: Concur with Squirrel, maybe you should have a `LEFT(group,1)` as your partition

Comment: You need to explain what happens if there are other groups besides the ones mentioned and when the number of rows in a group exceeds 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the concatting to the outer query:

```
select *, CASE WHEN new_id_bit > 200 THEN ... ELSE concat(ID, CASE WHEN group = 'bfd' THEN -1 ELSE 200 END + NEW_id_bit) end

FROM(
SELECT id, group,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group order by ID)  as new_id_bit
FROM table2)x
order by id;
```

I don't know what you want to do if it's over 200; put your own logic in place of ... , for example `CASE WHEN new_id_bit > 200 THEN 200 ELSE new_id_bit END`

You could also/instead use a where clause to restrict to only those with a new ID bit less than 200

Comment: I am very new in IT field trying my hands on SQL, this helped me a lot understand the functionality Thank you!

Comment: No problem! You could have kept it the way you had it, by the way, but it would have meant repeating the lengthy `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group order by ID)` everywhere you needed it. By doing it in  the inner query you can make an alias of it, and then it's easier to reuse in many places like `CASE WHEN x = blah THEN x ELSE x + 1 END` - it's a lot more readable than `CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y) = blah THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y) ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y) + 1 END` :D

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id,
 t1.g,
 convert(varchar(3), t1.id)
    + convert ( varchar(3),
   case when g = 'bfd' then ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by case when g = 'bfd' then 1 else 2 end order by id) - 1
   else (ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by case when g = 'bfd' then 1 else 2 end order by id)) + 200 end)
from T t1
```

output

```
101 bfd 1010
102 bfd 1021
123 klm 123201
563 kln 563202
693 klm 693203
```

Comment: this doesn't seems to address OP's requirement on `stop at 200 for particular group`

Comment: I was struggling in getting this order too! Thanks for helping me out! this helped!